# Obtaining Cypher queries for creating existing nodes and relationships in future

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is their any way to obtain/generate Cypher queries for creating all nodes and relationships in the future, say on another machine, on completely new installation of Neo4j (in the same way that in examples there is set of Cypher queries given for creating Movie graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neo4j-shell has a `dump` command that can output the complete Cypher dump. I'm not sure how well it performs with large graphs.

```
neo4j-shell -c dump > backup.txt
```

Comment: Neo4j 3.0.4 CE does not have Neo4jShell.bat. What should be done in that case?

Comment: Also now I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/neo4j/shell/StartClient : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`. Also should neo4j be running for this command to work?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, [GraphGists](http://portal.graphgist.org/) might be of interest as a way to publicly document and share Cypher queries. You can use @MartinPreusse's suggestion as a way to generate the Cypher queries.